# Is it possible to add an x-axis line for each row in data in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a time-series chart in power-bi. To this table I have connected an event-table with the following columns: ID, StartDate, Description.

I would like to add a x-axis line to my time-series chart for each row (StartDate) in my event-table. Is this possible to do in Power Bi? Manually adding them is not a solution.

When I tried adding a line based on the StartDate as per below it only results in one constant line. [image: example]

Below is a snippet of my time-series chart:
[image: timeserieschart]

Comment: Could you add a snip of your time-series chart.

Comment: Sure, I added it now @SamNseir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the native visuals, but there are a couple of options.

1. Have a look at mimicking error lines:   https://bonbonsguide.com/wp/blog/2022/09/how-to-utilize-error-bars-in-power-bi-to-visualize-uncertainty-in-your-data/
2. [Charticulator](https://charticulator.com/) is a relatively quick to learn custom PowerBI visual so if you have some time, have a go/play.
3. If you use the native 'Line chart' visual, it does show the vertical line through the data point on hover.

Comment: I assumed so. thank you Sam!